# Find id's by searching tag combination

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a table with two fields candidate_id and keyword_id. I needs to list all the candidates/candidate_id having keyword_id 5 and 6. Somebody please help me to write a single mysql query for this please.

Comment: SELECT candidate_id  FROM table WHERE keyword_id IN (5.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option that is simple to adapt to more than just two keyword_id's would be...

```
SELECT
  candidate_id
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  keyword_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
  candidate_id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT keyword_id) = 2
```

An alternative could be...

```
SELECT
  k1.candidate_id
FROM
  yourTable  AS k1
INNER JOIN
  yourTable  AS k2
    ON k1.candidate_id = k2.candidate_id
WHERE
      k1.keyword_id = 1
  AND k2.keyword_id = 2
```

It should be noted, however, that neither of these options scales very well (as you increase the number of candidates, keywords, and number of keywords that you search for.

How to deal with this poor scaling totally depends on your data, and your needs.  It's too broad and subjective a topic to discuss in a SO answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Dems for your quick solution. Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite unclear what you exactly want, but this query gives you all candidates which have at least one match with a given keyword (using LIKE searches for matches within a keyword. If a keyword 'php' is given and the keyword in your database is 'php programmer', this match will show up). Something like this should do the trick, if this is what you're after.

```
  $sQueryExtension = '';
  foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $sQueryExtension .= " OR `keyword` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
  }
  $sQueryExtension = substr($sQueryExtension, 3); // skip first OR

  $sQuery = "
    SELECT candidate.* 
    FROM candidate, match_table 
    WHERE candidate.id = match_table.candidate_id 
    AND match_table.keyword_id IN (
      SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE $sQueryExtension
    );";
```

Comment: I just need candidate_id having keyword_id 5 and 6.

Comment: And what about another candidate, where you need id 6 and 14?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need records having
1. Either 5 or 6 OR
2. Do you need candidates having both 5 and 6?

For case 1,

```
SELECT candidate_id
FROM <table>
WHERE keyword_id in (5,6);
```

For case 2,

```
SELECT candidate_id
FROM (SELECT candidate_id, count(distinct keyword_id)
      FROM <table>
      WHERE keyword_id in (5, 6)
      GROUP BY candidate_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT keyword_id) > 1);
```